# How to get the windows messages according to the child?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am creating a form inside another form. In the child form I have created taskbar button. I am overriding WndProc in the button.I am referring https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10171/Adding-a-Minimize-to-tray-button-to-a-Form-s-caption bar. But whenever I am getting messages(mouse coordinates) , it is given with respect to the parent form. This makes trouble in calculations .I want those with respect to child form.How to achieve this?

This is the code for form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.TopLevel = false;
        form2.AutoScroll = true;
        form2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top;
        form2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(form2);
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

this is form2.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    TyronM.MinTrayBtn Pin_Button;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Pin_Button = new TyronM.MinTrayBtn(this);
        Pin_Button.MinTrayBtnClicked += new TyronM.MinTrayBtnClickedEventHandler(this.Pin_Button_Clicked);
        
    }
    public void Pin_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Pin button got Clicked");
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
    {
        const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;

        switch (message.Msg)
        {
            case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                int command = message.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
                if (command == SC_MOVE)
                    return;
                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref message);
    }
}
```

And this is for button.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Resources;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TyronM {
public delegate void MinTrayBtnClickedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class.
/// </summary>
public class MinTrayBtn : NativeWindow {
    bool pinned = false;
    
    bool pressed = false;
    Size wnd_size = new Size();
    public bool captured;
    Form parent;
    public event MinTrayBtnClickedEventHandler MinTrayBtnClicked;

    #region Constants
    const int WM_SIZE = 5;
    const int WM_SYNCPAINT = 136;
    const int WM_MOVE = 3;
    const int WM_ACTIVATE = 6;
    const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN =513;
    const int WM_LBUTTONUP =514;
    const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK =515;
    const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 512;

    const int WM_PAINT = 15;

    const int WM_GETTEXT = 13;

    const int WM_NCCREATE =129;
    const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 161;
    const int WM_NCLBUTTONUP = 162;
    const int WM_NCMOUSEMOVE = 160;
    const int WM_NCACTIVATE =134;
    const int WM_NCPAINT = 133;
    const int WM_NCHITTEST = 132;
    const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 163;

    const int VK_LBUTTON = 1;
    
    const int SM_CXSIZE = 30;
    const int SM_CYSIZE = 31;               
    #endregion

    #region Extra Constants
    const int WM_MBUTTONUP = 0x0208;                    
    #endregion
    #region WinAPI Imports
    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int GetWindowDC(int hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int SetCapture(int hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int GetSysColor(int nIndex);
    
    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int nIndex);
    #endregion

    #region Constructor and Handle-Handler ^^
    public MinTrayBtn(Form parent) {
        parent.HandleCreated += new EventHandler(this.OnHandleCreated);
        parent.HandleDestroyed+= new EventHandler(this.OnHandleDestroyed);
        parent.TextChanged+= new EventHandler(this.OnTextChanged);
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    // Listen for the control's window creation and then hook into it.
    internal void OnHandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e){
        // Window is now created, assign handle to NativeWindow.
        AssignHandle(((Form)sender).Handle);
    }
    internal void OnHandleDestroyed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Window was destroyed, release hook.
        ReleaseHandle();
    }
    
    // Changing the Text invalidates the Window, so we got to Draw the Button again
    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        DrawButton();
    }
    #endregion

    #region WndProc
    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
        //label3.Text = "Button pressed: " + pressed;
        //label4.Text = "Mouse captured: " + captured;

        // Change the Pressed-State of the Button when the User pressed the
        // left mouse button and moves the cursor over the button
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK ||m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN || m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONUP 
            ||m.Msg == WM_MBUTTONUP
            )

            MessageBox.Show("click happened");
        if(m.Msg==WM_MOUSEMOVE) {
            Point pnt2 = new Point((int)m.LParam);
            Size rel_pos2 = new Size(parent.PointToClient(new Point(parent.Location.X, parent.Location.Y)));
            // Not needed because SetCapture seems to convert the cordinates anyway
            //pnt2 = PointToClient(pnt2);
            pnt2-=rel_pos2;
            //label2.Text = "Cursor @"+pnt2.X+"/"+pnt2.Y;

            if(pressed) {
                Point pnt = new Point((int)m.LParam);
                Size rel_pos = new Size(parent.PointToClient(new Point(parent.Location.X, parent.Location.Y)));
                //pnt = PointToClient(pnt);
                pnt-=rel_pos;

                if(!MouseinBtn(pnt)) {
                    pressed = false;
                    DrawButton();
                }

            } else {
                if((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)&(-32768))!=0) {
                    Point pnt = new Point((int)m.LParam);
                    Size rel_pos = new Size(parent.PointToClient(new Point(parent.Location.X, parent.Location.Y)));
                    //pnt = PointToClient(pnt);
                    pnt-=rel_pos;

                    if(MouseinBtn(pnt)) {
                        pressed = true;
                        DrawButton();
                    }
                }
            }  
        }

        // Ignore Double-Clicks on the Traybutton
        if(m.Msg==WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK) {
                Point pnt = new Point((int)m.LParam);
                Size rel_pos = new Size(parent.PointToClient(new Point(parent.Location.X, parent.Location.Y)));
                pnt = parent.PointToClient(pnt);
                pnt-=rel_pos;
                if(MouseinBtn(pnt)) {
                    return;
                }
        }

        #region NOT WORKING
        // Button released and eventually clicked 
        if(m.Msg==WM_LBUTTONUP)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            captured = false;

            if(pressed) {
                pressed = false;
                DrawButton();

                Point pnt = new Point((int)m.LParam);
                Size rel_pos = new Size(parent.PointToClient(new Point(parent.Location.X, parent.Location.Y)));
                pnt-=rel_pos;
                if(MouseinBtn(pnt)) {
                    //TrayButton_clicked();
                    EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
                    if (MinTrayBtnClicked != null)
                        MinTrayBtnClicked(this, e);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
        // Clicking the Button - Capture the Mouse and await until the Uses relases the Button again
        if(m.Msg==WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN) {
            //MessageBox.Show("clicked");
            Point pnt = new Point((int)m.LParam);
            Size rel_pos = new Size(parent.PointToClient(new Point(parent.Location.X, parent.Location.Y)));
            pnt = parent.PointToClient(pnt);
            pnt-=rel_pos;

            if(MouseinBtn(pnt)) {
                MessageBox.Show("clicked");
                pressed = true;
                DrawButton();
                SetCapture((int)parent.Handle);
                captured = true;
                return;
            }
        }

        // Drawing the Button and getting the Real Size of the Window
        if(m.Msg == WM_ACTIVATE || m.Msg==WM_SIZE || m.Msg==WM_SYNCPAINT || m.Msg==WM_NCACTIVATE || m.Msg==WM_NCCREATE || m.Msg==WM_NCPAINT || m.Msg==WM_NCACTIVATE || m.Msg==WM_NCHITTEST || m.Msg==WM_PAINT) {
            if(m.Msg==WM_SIZE) wnd_size = new Size(new Point((int)m.LParam));
            DrawButton();
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Button-Specific Functions
    public bool MouseinBtn(Point click) {
        int btn_width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZE);
        int btn_height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZE);
        Size btn_size = new Size(btn_width, btn_height);
        
        Point pos = new Point(wnd_size.Width - 3 * btn_width - 12 - (btn_width - 18)+7, 6+4);
                    
        return click.X>=pos.X && click.X<=pos.X+btn_size.Width &&
               click.Y>=pos.Y && click.Y<=pos.Y+btn_size.Height;
    }

    public void DrawButton() {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc((IntPtr)GetWindowDC((int)parent.Handle)); //m.HWnd));
        DrawButton(g, pressed);
    }

    public void DrawButton(Graphics g, bool pressed) {
        int btn_width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZE);
        int btn_height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZE);
        
        //Point pos = new Point(wnd_size.Width-3*btn_width-12-(btn_width-18),6);
        Point pos = new Point(wnd_size.Width - 3 * btn_width - 12 - (btn_width - 18)+7, 6+4);
        
        // real button size
        btn_width-=2;
        btn_height-=4;
            
        Color light = SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
        Color icon = SystemColors.ControlText;
        Color background = SystemColors.Control;
        Color shadow1 = SystemColors.ControlDark;
        Color shadow2 = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;

        Color tmp1, tmp2;

        if(pressed) {
            tmp1 = shadow2;
            tmp2 = light;
        } else {
            tmp1 = light;
            tmp2 = shadow2;
        }

        g.DrawLine(new Pen(tmp1),pos, new Point(pos.X+btn_width-1,pos.Y));
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(tmp1),pos, new Point(pos.X,pos.Y+btn_height-1));

        if(pressed) {
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(shadow1),pos.X+1, pos.Y+1, pos.X+btn_width-2, pos.Y+1);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(shadow1),pos.X+1, pos.Y+1, pos.X+1, pos.Y+btn_height-2);
        } else {
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(shadow1),pos.X+btn_width-2, pos.Y+1, pos.X+btn_width-2, pos.Y+btn_height-2);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(shadow1),pos.X+1, pos.Y+btn_height-2, pos.X+btn_width-2, pos.Y+btn_height-2);
        }

        g.DrawLine(new Pen(tmp2),pos.X+btn_width-1, pos.Y+0, pos.X+btn_width-1, pos.Y+btn_height-1);
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(tmp2),pos.X+0, pos.Y+btn_height-1, pos.X+btn_width-1, pos.Y+btn_height-1);
        
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(background),pos.X+1+Convert.ToInt32(pressed), pos.Y+1+Convert.ToInt32(pressed), btn_width-3,btn_height-3);


        #region Added Code
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(icon),pos.X+(float)0.5625*btn_width+Convert.ToInt32(pressed),pos.Y+(float)0.6428*btn_height+Convert.ToInt32(pressed),btn_width*(float)0.1875,btn_height*(float)0.143);
        g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("red_Pushpin.jfif"),new Rectangle( pos,new Size(btn_width,btn_height)));
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion

}
}
```

This is code for main

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

This is the screenshot of the winform.
[image]

EDIT:
Upon investigation I found that WM_LBUTTONUP(Mouse left button up) is not triggered. Or it is not coming inside WndProc.

EDIT1:
It seems there was a problem in brackets.I changed the if conditions into switch case. This somewhat cleared the "Mouse left button up" problem. Now it is properly triggering. The remaining problem is mouse points based on parent form.

Comment: It would probably be useful to see the code in this case in order to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: Probably you don't fully understand what you're doing here. In your case `Pin_button` is not a real button. It does not have a handle and it does not have a `WndProc`, it's just a place on a `Form2` that has been drawn to look like a button. `MinTrayBtn` class does not create any button, it hooks `WndProc` of `Form2` and paints button on a frame. So it's normal that all mouse coordinates you get are related to `Form2` handle.

Comment: @Sergey Even in that case, the "left mouse button up" event should come to WndProc. But it is not happening.

Comment: @prabhakaran ensure that `SetCapture` is called inside `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` handler and also remove all `MessageBox.Show` calls since that could be the reason of stealing capture and suppressing `WM_LBUTTONUP`. Better use `Debug.WriteLine(` for tracing.